# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.

Tags: python

```
def populate_db(cur, csv_fp):
    rdr = csv.reader(csv_fp)
    cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO tickets (Key , \
        Id  , \
        Project , \
        Type , \
        Status , \
        Priority , \
        Assignee , \
        Reporter , \
        Created , \
        Updated , \
        Date_due , \
        Summary , \
        Description , \
        Components , \
        Affects_Versions , \
        Fix_Versions  , \
        Environment , \
        Resolution , \
        Votes) \
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', rdr)
```

This code works fine on my pycharm editor with 2.7 interpreter. 
However on linux box with 2.6 it gives above error.
Please direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was working in IDE (Pycharm) but not in production, I switched to using csv reader with dictionary. Dropped sqlite.

```
def populate_dict(mydict, csv_fh):
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csv_fh, ['Key', 'Description'])
    mydict.extend(rdr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using list literal or make rdr a tuple. Because rdr is treated as a input sequence, you need to convert it to a tuple or list:

```
[rdr]
#or try this
(rdr,)
```

Comment: File "./nalrt2tkt.py", line 75, in populate_db
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', [rdr])
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: File "./nalrt2tkt.py", line 75, in populate_db
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (rdr,))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: You should follow the instruction on this article . https://medium.com/@felipe.f.m/sqlite3-programmingerror-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-2e3583d7e034

Comment: Thanks @Duck_dragon. However these did not help out.

Comment: What happens if you remove `executemany` and try with `execute`. `cur.execute(' INSERT INTO ----  ' , (rdr,))`

Comment: It throws same error of "incorrect number of bindings".

Comment: I added a  line
        rdr = [rdr]
Now it throws error "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
"